# В админ панели реализовать checbox

Tags: php, html, sql, smarty

Добрый день! Необходима помощь в том как реализовать в админ панели, checbox-ы для опций отеля. В данный момент в базе находится таблица с опциями + связь многие ко многим. Все работает корректно, если записывать на прямую в базу все работает ровно. Теперь вопрос: Как сделать так, чтобы можно было insert-ить статус активности/неактивности.
Опции выгружаются в комнатах.

таблица `toption`: id, label, optfilename, descript
таблица `troomoptions`: id, roomid, optionid, hotelid

```
function optionGetValue(){
    $cn = dbConnect();
    $q = mysql_query("SELECT optfilename, descript FROM toptions");
    $otionList = Array();
    while($out=mysql_fetch_array($q))
            array_push($otionList,$out);
    mysql_close($cn);
    return $otionList;
}
```

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то? В PHP коде ожидаем получить переменную (имя чекбокса)... если переменная пришла - значит чекбокс был отмечен, если переменная не пришла, значит чекбокс был выключен. Или вас интересует что-то другое?

Comment: Именно это интересует, если я правильно понимаю нужно сделать событие. Но опыта в этом не имею, буду благодарен за помощь. 
Сейчас сделал выгрузку опций из базы:   <label for="roomsoptions">Перечень опций комнаты</label> {foreach from=$option key=id item=val}
<p>{$val.descript}</p>
 <p><input type="checkbox" name="roomsoptions" class="form-control" id="roomsoptions"></p>
<img src="./static/images/iconoptions/{$val.optfilename}"> {/foreach}

Comment: Насколько я понимаю, в БД нужно еще создать поле, которое будет boolean, и которое будет при нажатии на кнопку, складывать в зависимости от активности бокса значение 1 или 2. А при выгрузке этим полем будет проверятся активность/неактивность бокса

Comment: ENUM(0, 1) будет в самый раз для поля в таблице MySQL.

Comment: С полем проблем нет, но вопрос в том как в цикле сделать условие и проверять. Потому что в таблице(какой комнате, какие опции) опции объедены cancat т.е. id комнаты и след. поле option(в нем идет 1,2,3)

Comment: Т.е. не в таблице, в запросе.
Сейчас выгружаются все опции, но нет проверки на активность бокса, и нет Insert-а в таблицу. Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: Добавил в передающий массив status и optionid. все приходит норм, теперь если я правильно понимаю мне нужно в value задать условие:
if val.status==1 делай checbox cheched, иначе ..... просто пусто?

Comment: В общем идея верная, проверяете значение и отмечаете checked, если 1.

Comment: Alex, направьте на путь истинны:
 <input type="checkbox" name="roomsoptions"  id="$val['id']" value="1" "{if $val['status']} checked="checked"{/if}"/>
В данном случае он для всех комнат выгружает 2 галочки, что то упустил, не могу понять что.....

Comment: Т.е. всего два чек-бокса или появляются дубли? А так кавычки лишние вокруг конструкции, как мне видится `"{if $val['status']} checked="checked"{/if}"` (он не нужны) и перед `/>` должен быть пробел.

Comment: Вообщем была проблема с функцией на админке и на отображении, и связь БД была в одном поле не с той таблицей.
Итоговый корректный вариант:
<input type="checkbox" name="roomsoptions"  id="$val['id']" value="1" "{if $val['status']} checked="checked" {/if}" />

Теперь еще нужно сделать Insert и update, подскажите в каком направлении двигаться?

Comment: Нет я соврал, не корректно, все равно 2 checbox-а((((

Comment: Проблема в том, что у меня приходит массив опций, а статус опции не проверяется по id комнаты. Возможно ли реализовать в одной функции выборку всех опций а также выборку опций имеющих статус 1 для каждой комнаты? Или нужно писать отдельную функцию на статус?

Comment: Если у вас в таблице с опциями пока нет id комнаты, то это нужно сделать, добавить в таблицу поле `room_id`, где будет указан id комнаты, и в функцию добавить параметр `room_id` и исправить SQL запрос, добавив `WHERE` конструкцию.

Comment: trooms содержит id, hotelsid, rooms
toptions содержит id,label,optfile,descript
troomsoptions содержит id, roomid,optionid,hotelsid,status
т.е нужно еще добавить в toption поле roomid?

Comment: Все пашет, была проблема в sql запросе, там неправильно сравнение было. Сейчас все работает правильно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была проблема в запросе, сейчас все работает корректно.